# playground - timeout running go build

Tags: go, go-playground

When I try to run code snippet on [playground (snippet)](https://play.golang.org/p/CKVtN4MRW3F) , I get an error:

```
timeout running go build
go: finding module for package github.com/spf13/viper
go: downloading github.com/spf13/viper v1.7.1
go: found github.com/spf13/viper in github.com/spf13/viper v1.7.1
go: downloading github.com/magiconair/properties v1.8.1
go: downloading github.com/hashicorp/hcl v1.0.0
go: downloading github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure v1.1.2
go: downloading github.com/spf13/jwalterweatherman v1.0.0
go: downloading github.com/spf13/cast v1.3.0
go: downloading github.com/pelletier/go-toml v1.2.0
go: downloading github.com/spf13/pflag v1.0.3
go: downloading gopkg.in/ini.v1 v1.51.0
go: downloading github.com/subosito/gotenv v1.2.0
go: downloading gopkg.in/yaml.v2 v2.2.4
go: downloading github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify v1.4.7
go: downloading github.com/spf13/afero v1.1.2
go: downloading golang.org/x/text v0.3.2
go: downloading golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20190624142023-c5567b49c5d0
```

To run code "playground" have to download [viper](https://github.com/spf13/viper) and It's transitive dependencies.

I am assuming the "playground" has limit to get dependencies.
Could I solve it❓

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> playground - timeout running go build [...] Could I solve it❓

No. Sorry.

The Playground is a *playground* and not a build server or an application server.